# how to find variables location in memory without source code?

Tags: memory, gdb

Basically I want to find the address/location of a variable in gdb?

I know normally the variable are store at `rbp` but don't know how to locate them using gdb.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to find the address/location of a variable in gdb?

That is possible, but the approach is different depending on whether the variable is a global or a local.

> I know normally the variable are store at rbp

Local variables are stored *at some offset* of the frame pointer. `%RBP` is often used as a frame pointer in *unoptimized* binaries.

To find such variable, you'll need to know how to read machine code, and then you can find it. GDB will not help you with finding it in code that is compiled without debug info (it can't).

> without source code

Source code has *nothing* to do with this -- GDB never looks at the source code, except to display it to you.

On to concrete example. Suppose you have the following source:

```
int foo(int *ip) { return *ip + 42; }
int main()
{
  int j = 1;
  return foo(&j);
}
```

Compiling this without debug info and without optimizations, results in:

```
(gdb) disas main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x000000000000060d <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000000000000060e <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000000611 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000000615 <+8>:     movl   $0x1,-0x4(%rbp)
   0x000000000000061c <+15>:    lea    -0x4(%rbp),%rax
   0x0000000000000620 <+19>:    mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000000623 <+22>:    callq  0x5fa <foo>
   0x0000000000000628 <+27>:    leaveq
   0x0000000000000629 <+28>:    retq
End of assembler dump.
```

here you can clearly see that `j` is being stored at negative offset `4` off `%rbp`.

You can set a breakpoint on `foo`, and use GDB to examine its value like so:

```
(gdb) b foo
Breakpoint 1 at 0x5fe
(gdb) run

Breakpoint 1, 0x00005555555545fe in foo ()
(gdb) up
#1  0x0000555555554628 in main ()
(gdb) x/x $rbp-4
0x7fffffffdbcc: 0x00000001      // indeed that is expected value of j
```